# Re-duplicate a broken physical standby database?

Tags: oracle, database-administration

On my primary database some of archivelog files was accidentally deleted and not applied on the standby database. Now I want to recreate re-duplicate my standby database. I'm not sure about the exactly/correct steps  in order to not broke something on production database.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to restore standby, copy database files without a control file and online redolog.

1) The easiest way:

- Stop the primary database.
- Stop the standby.
- Run a cold backup of data files with operating system commands (copy or cp), without a control file and online redolog on primary host.
- Copy files to standy host.
- Run the primary database
- Create new standby controlfile
  `ALTER DATABASE CREATE STANDBY CONTROLFILE AS '/tmp/standbycontrol20191029.ctl'`;
- Copy new standby controlfile `standbycontrol20191029.ctl` to standby host.
- Replace old standby controlfile with the new standby controlfile.
- Start standby database.

2) Option without stopping the primary database.

- make a hot backup of the database using the `rman` utility.
- Copy files to standy host.
- Restore files on standby using `rman` utility.

Comment: I was ablet to use first method, the only think I did - recreated the standby files thx

Comment: You need to create new standby controlfile.